# How to delete completely Dokan plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I deactivated and delete Dokan plugin but this only delete files but not delete setting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the database, settings or whatever saved for the pluging. Take a look at this article - https://wpsites.net/wordpress-tips/cleaning-up-left-over-plugin-database-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in many cases Dokan usages the WooCommerce' functionality/mechanism. As the WooCommerce doesn't delete the database table after deactivating the plugin, Dokan doesn't have this option either. If you really need to delete the database tables, you will be needing to delete those tables manually, from the Database.